# How to set up python multiprocessing on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am using the `multiprocessing` module in `Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`.

I am trying to use the simplest toy code found online:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def foo():
    print('hello')

p = Process(target=foo)
p.start()
```

I have tried with and without the `if __name__ == "__main__":`

I keep getting the error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\pboswell003\\PwC_Projects\\anonymize_SAP\\anonymization\\SAP\\<input>'
```

I am confused what the `<input>` part should be, and what file exactly it is trying to open.

UPDATE:  I have taken @ShadowRanger 's advice and tried running from a script.  Now, I am experiencing the issue of being unable to debug what is happening. That is, nothing seems to happen.  If I add `time.sleep(10)` to the function, the script executes in the same time, leading me to believe the workers are not being spawned and used.

NEW QUESTION:  How do I interactively test my code and see the results of the worker threads when I run the script from a command line interface?

Answer (score 2):

You're likely doing this from an interactive interpreter.

1. Don't do that on Windows (or at all, really) with the `multiprocessing` module; write a short script, use that (or use threads, which don't have the forking simulation issue)
2. The `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard is non-optional on Windows; terrible things will happen without it. It must exist, and it must guard against any launching of `Process` (including via `Pool`); top-level `Process` launches that are unguarded are a *bad* idea. This is a uniquely Windows problem because the forking simulation used on Windows relies on that guard to allow it to reinitialize the state of the `__main__` module in each child process, simulating a fork; if the guard isn't there, you'll end up trying to create more child processes of the child, which create more children, etc. It's a process spawn bomb, don't do it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding.  Happy New Year!  Thank you for your feedback, and I have some follow-up questions.  I have edited my question to include additional steps taken and a new question

Comment: @PabloBoswell: I can't reproduce your issue. Here's [an online adaptation of your code](https://tio.run/##XY@xagMxDIZ3P4Wgg20IISFbwe/QIdBRmJwcm9qWsXUcffrLJdcu0Sjp//Sp/UrkelnX0LlAmbOk1vlGY6R6h1Qad4GvvXOAQYJDfBcstOUm9bcgqZBSEwUIzMZ@Ktiq9VTF6Eg5sz5AyPOI7tpnsq/xM3McmaiZ88kqlQIgVl8IEZwDjVh8qoh6p72fNno0v1RtAT7gylC83CJEXuA71YmXAQv3n7GbgPv/wWyIO4nbPHeNdnxRjV3XBw "Python 3 – Try It Online")  (`set_start_method` is used to match `multiprocessing`'s behavior on Windows); it runs as expected, including sleeping 10 seconds before the process exits.